# Cant build project using Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

When i open my gradle project in Android Studio, it will show build successful in the terminal while after that it shows the following error:

```
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution
'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'. Task 'wrapper' not found in root project 'gradle'.
```

Althoug I am running gradle 1.9, I dont know why this error is shown

Comment: Try importing your project. When you import, select you top level `build.gradle`. That *MIGHT* help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle wrapper make sure these lines are added in to your top level build.gradle file

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.9'    
}
```

Also your **`$YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties`** should point to write distribution url, I have observed that distrinutionUrl defined in **gradle-wrapper.properties** file changes aumatically according to the gradle version defined in wrapper task while syncing. If the task is not defined by **default it changes to 1.6** .

So check it and make it correct

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-bin.zip
```

And finally wherever you have defined your gradle dependencies class-path in build.gradle files they all should be

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
```

0.7.* is used for gradle version 1.9 , you can make all the changes as per your gradle version.

Comment: I have checked all the files as u mentioned,still no solution

Comment: Check File > Settings > gradle and let me know which option is ticked there ?

Comment: Make sure you have included wrapper and all specially the distributionUrl because it change after every sync if wrapper is configured wrong after doing all changed. try File > Invalidate Cache/ Restart some time it does a great job.

Comment: is you problem got resolved ? which version you were using earlier ?